# Desktop to Web communication for a centralized database

Tags: desktop, portal, centralized

I have developed a web portal with a web hosted database, a desktop application with a desktop database. A master database on the web is supposed to be centralized, hosting data of both multiple desktop apps and multiple web portals.

I know we can make multiple websites using sharepoint but how to develop a centralized database for both web and desktop apps?

Is there any SharePoint API available to communicate a web app with a desktop app?

Or any other solutions?

thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with oData as a data interchange protocol and treat sharepoint as your central data storage layer.

http://www.odata.org/